# Load more UICell in the bottom of the UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I started an iOS project and I'm working with UITableView to display a list of pilots with images . I did pagination on my api and I tried to load more once you scrolled the tableview. the problem that I got is that the new cells are always displayed on top of the tableview not in the bottom. Please check on my code if there is a solution I will be grateful

```
- (void)loadData :(NSInteger)page {
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.navigationController.view animated:YES];
url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%ld",NSLocalizedString(@"get_pilots",nil),mainDelegate.idAccount,@"?page=",(long)page]];
task = [restObject GET:url :mainDelegate.token completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    NSMutableDictionary* jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization
                                         JSONObjectWithData:data
                                         options:kNilOptions
                                         error:nil];
    NSArray *pilotKey = [jsonResponse objectForKey:@"pilot"];
    for (NSDictionary *pilotItem in pilotKey ){
        PilotObject *pilotObj = [PilotObject new];
        [pilotObj getPilot:pilotObj :pilotItem];
        [_pilotsAll addObject:pilotObj];
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [hud hideAnimated:YES];
        [self checkTableView:_pilotsDisplay :self.view];
        [viewPilots.tableViewPilots reloadData];
    });
}];
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
if (currentPage == totalPages) {
    return [_pilotsDisplay count];
}
return [_pilotsDisplay count] + 1;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (indexPath.row == [_pilotsDisplay count] - 1 && currentPage<totalPages ) {
    [self loadData:++currentPage];
    NSLog(@"current page : = %ld",(long)currentPage);
}
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if (indexPath.row == [_pilotsDisplay count]) {
    static NSString *identifier = @"PilotCellTableViewCell";
    PilotCellTableViewCell *cell = (PilotCellTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    cell.hidden=YES;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = (UIActivityIndicatorView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    return cell;

} else {
    PilotObject *pilotObjDisplay = nil;
    pilotObjDisplay = [_pilotsDisplay objectAtIndex:[_pilotsDisplay count]-1-indexPath.row];
    static NSString *identifier = @"PilotCellTableViewCell";
    PilotCellTableViewCell *cell = (PilotCellTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    cell.hidden=NO;
    cell.image.image = pilotObjDisplay.imageDisplayPilot;
    cell.titleLabel.text = pilotObjDisplay.firstName;
    cell.subTitleLabel.text = pilotObjDisplay.lastName;
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:NSLocalizedString(@"gray_background", nil)];
    return cell;
}
return nil;
}
```

Comment: Check your response how data came? Because tableview only represents the data that you gave to it.

Comment: the data is fine it comes with pagination and it woks on android .
my problem is how to put the new data in the bottom of the tableview not in the top on iOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you are taking 2 array _pilotsDisplay and _pilotsAll ?

If not necessary then you can also do pagination using one `NSMutableArray` which you can use in both cases while fetching data from server as well as while filling data to `UITableView`.

Remember one thing only initialise your `NSMutableArray` in `viewDidLoad` method. And when you received new data use `addObject` method of `NSMutableArray` which you are already using. And then call `reloadData` method of `UITableView`.

And in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` don't use calculation like `[_pilotsDisplay count]-1-indexPath.row`, simply use `indexPath.row`.

Answer (score 0):

Here, inserting rows to the tableview may help you.

```
[tableView beginUpdates];
NSArray *paths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[dataArray count]-1 inSection:1]];
[[self tableView] insertRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
[tableView endUpdates];
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add cells to a tableview. what you should do is add data to the tableview's datasource (in your case, _pilotsDisplay) and then simply reload the table. If you want the new data to appear at bottom or in any particular order, you should do that to your datasource (the array).